# Построчная запись строк из textarea в MySQL

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Помогите!
Есть код:

```
<form action="adminpex.php" type="post">
<b>Выберите город</b><br>
<select  name="id">
  <option>Выберите город</option>
   <option value="1">Москва</option>
   <option value="2">Питер</option>
   <option value="3">Омск</option>
    <option value="4">Саратов</option>
    <option value="5">Мурманск</option>
    <option value="6">Краснодар</option>
</select>
<hr>
<br>
<b>Причина заявки </b> <br><b>( каждая с новой строчки! )</b><br>
<textarea name="permission" value="zapros" class="textarea_1"></textarea>
<hr><br>
<input type="submit" value="Послать заявку" class="button_1">
</form>
</center>
</html>

<?php

    $link = mysql_connect('*********' ,'**********' ,'tbz4MQ4zc4xy' ,'*******');
         if (!$link) {
            echo " Подключение к бд не удалось ". mysql_error();
         }

         $db_selected = mysql_select_db('****');

         if (!$db_selected) {
             echo " Выбрать бд не удалось";
         }

if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) )
    {
        $id = !empty( $_POST['id'] ) ? $_POST['id'] : '';
        $permission = !empty( $_POST['permission'] ) ? $_POST['permission'] : '';
        $query = mysql_query ( "INSERT INTO permissions VALUES ('$id','$permission')" );

        if ( !$query )
        {
            echo '<h4 style="color: RED"><div class="block2">Произошла ошибка, попробуйте позже: ';
            echo mysql_error();
            echo '</div></h4>';
            mysql_close($link);
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<div class="block2">Запрос выполнен! </div>';
            mysql_close($link);
        }
    }

?>
```

Как мне записывать данные с Textarea построчно, скажем:

Жалоба1
Предложение2
Предложение3

В бд нужно, чтобы каждая строчка это + 1 строка в таблице.

Прошу помочь.

Что нужно добавить/заменить?

Comment: [deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php)

    Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и будет 
    удалено в будущем. Используйте вместо него MySQLi или PDO_MySQL. 
    Смотрите также инструкцию MySQL: выбор API и соответствующий FAQ 
    для получения более подробной информации. Альтернативы для данной 
    функции:

[mysqli_connect()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysqli-connect.php)

[PDO::__construct()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.construct.php)

Answer (score 1):

В простом виде это должно выглядеть как-то так:

```
$permissions = explode("\n", $_POST['permission']);
foreach ($permissions as $permission) {
    mysql_query('INSERT INTO permissions VALUES ("' . $id . '", "' . $permission . '")');
}
```